# Efficiency: 2D-list to dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, list, dictionary

I have a 2D-list.

```
l = [[100, 1], [43, 2], [201, 1], [5, 7], ...]
```

I want to convert the list into a dictionary where the second element serves as key. The value of each key should be a list of all first elements, that have the key as second element.
The dictionary for this sample list should look like that:

```
{
    1: [100, 201],
    2: [43],
    7: [5],
    ...
}
```

I have two solutions for this conversion. Which one of them is more efficient and why? Also: Is there another more efficient solution?

Solution1:

```
d = {}
for elem in l:
    if elem[1] in d:
        d[elem[1]].append(elem[0])
    else:
        d[elem[1]] = [elem[0]]
```

Solution2:

```
d = {}

for elem in l:
    d[elem[1]] = []

for elem in l:
    d[elem[1]].append(elem[0])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with you're two solutions, they're fine and efficient:

1. Solution 1 iterates the list once, but performs a dictionary look up twice. Since this is about O(1), and you have 2, I would say this is 2xN.
2. Solution 2 iterates the list twice, with one lookup each time - again 2xN.

From a theoretical perspective these are identical. Run time I would wager they are very close as well. A more pythonic way (asking for forgiveness rather than permission ,thanks @tobias_k) that may improve the first solution is:

```
d = {}
for elem in l:
    try:
        d[elem[1]].append(elem[0])
    except KeyError:
        d[elem[1]] = [elem[0]]
```

If you have many repeating keys, this would be better, since the overhead of an exception would be much smaller than all the ifs (and only one lookup), so this would depend on the actual list in question. If you go for this solution you may want to read up on a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html).

**Some new info**

My guess was wrong! even though theoretically they are the same, and it seems like the amount of operations are the same, there is a difference. I'm guessing this has to do with Python's ability to optimize `if` statements.

Marking your first method `a`, your second one `b`, and the one I provided `c`, using the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/timeit.html) module I timed these methods for two lists:

```
l1=[(x,y) for x,y in zip(range(1000),range(1000,2000)]
l1=[(x,2) for x,y in range(1000)]
```

Results for `l1`:

Method `a` is fastest. 30% slower is `b`, and another 30% from that is `c`.

Results for `l2`:

Methods `a` and `b` are nearly identical (a still a bit faster), and `c` is a bit faster than both (which we expected).

I would say for practical purposes the first version is better than the second, but the 3d would be best if you have a lot of repeating keys. bottom line, theory is all well and good, but **the best method practically is list dependent.**

Comment: @tobias_k Fair enough, thanks. With Python I (wrongly) synonymize try-except with duck typing. I guess you could say "treat it as a list, and catch if not", but I agree it's a stretch.

Comment: That's still not really correct. The problem is not that it's not a list -- that would raise a TypeError or an AttributeError. The problem is that it's _not there at all_. I think the concept you are looking for is "asking for forgiveness instead of permission" or something like that. (The expression is often used in combination with duck typing, e.g. [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/175655/95456), in in this case it should not.)

Comment: @pogothebear Please accept your chosen answer for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: @kabanus I guess it's better to wait for other solutions.

Comment: @user32185 perhaps. In any case, a solution should be accepted if it answers - it can always be changed if something better comes along. I only make these comments to people with little rep, since they often confuse up-voting with accepting, or forget to accept (speaking from experience).

Answer (score 5):

```
l = [[100, 1], [43, 2], [201, 1], [5, 7]]
d = dict(l)
print(d)
```

it wil give you ouput as 
`{100: 1, 43: 2, 201: 1, 5: 7}`

Comment: It works only when there is at most 1 value for a key

Answer (score 4):

The 1st Solution is more efficient as it takes O(n) time to complete:
The if statement is O(1) since dictionary lookup is O(1).

The 2nd Solution is also O(n) but it runs twice, so O(n+n).

And in the 1st Solution, you could skip the if statement and directly append the elem[0], and add a try except block.

Comment: But the first loop does two operations in each iteration, so that's also O(2n).

Comment: @tobias_k exactly it does two operations. But my doubt is `if` is lil faster than `for` loop right ?

Comment: @VikasDamodar Yes, the first version is probably faster. The loop itself might have some (constant?) overhead, and you initialize only as many lists as needed, but still: Saying "it loops twice, so it must be slower than the other that loops only once" is misleading at best.

Comment: @tobias_k I got it, So what about my solution, Does it take more time ?

Comment: @VikasDamodar, you should check the complexity of setdefault, it may be faster than if but may not outperform exception handling.

Answer (score 3):

I think **solution 1** is more efficient than **solution 2**, Because it have only one loop. I think you can try the below code may be it is lil more efficient than **solution 1**

```
l = [[100, 1], [43, 2], [201, 1], [5, 7]]
d = {}
for k, v in l:
    d.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
print(d)
```

it gives o/p like this :

```
{1: [100, 201], 2: [43], 7: [5]}
```

Comment: It seems to me that this solution is consistently slower than OP **solution1**.

Comment: @user32185 In OP's solution 1 it goes through an `if:..else`, So the time may lil decrease when it perform with set default,  because it performs once in each loop

Answer (score 1):

Your two solution will have same O(*n*). But you can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [[100, 1], [43, 2], [201, 1]]

d = defaultdict(list)

for v, k in l:
    d[k].append(v)

# defaultdict(list, {1: [100, 201], 2: [43]})
```

Some benchmarking:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np

l = np.random.randint(1, 100, [int(1e7), 2])

def dd(l):
    d = defaultdict(list)

    for i in l:
        d[i[1]].append(i[0])

    return d

def op(l):
    d = {}
    for elem in l:
        if elem[1] in d:
            d[elem[1]].append(elem[0])
        else:
            d[elem[1]] = [elem[0]]    

    return d

%timeit dd(l)  # 1 loop, best of 3: 8.22 s per loop
%timeit op(l)  # 1 loop, best of 3: 9.47 s per loop
```

Comment: It seems to me that this is 2x slower than the OP solution.

Comment: I'm not sure that is a good list for a benchmark. I used this 
 one `l = np.random.randint(1, 100, [int(1e7), 2])`

Comment: @user32185, updated with your inputs and a trivial improvement.